# Issue after SUPEE-8788 in removing samples downloadable products

Tags: magento1.9.2.4, supee-8788v2

I have just patched my Magento 1.9.2.4 with SUPEE-8788. Everything seems to be ok a part an issue in removing samples of downloadable products.
I mean when i click the "X" to remove the samples nothing happens [image]

If i check with firebug included in firefox i see an error:
"**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at Object.remove ((index):2113)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (prototype.js:391)
    at HTMLButtonElement.responder (prototype.js:5598)**"

Can anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, this is a bug in SUPEE-8788

Open samples.phtml inside `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable`

Find the function

> ```
> remove : function(event){
>     var element = $(Event.findElement(event, 'tr'));
>     alertAlreadyDisplayed = false;
>     if(element){
>         element.down('input[type="hidden"].__delete__').value = '1';
>         element.down('div.flex').remove();
>         element.addClassName('no-display');
>         element.addClassName('ignore-validate');
>         element.hide();
>     }
> },
> ```

and replace it with

> ```
> remove : function(event){
>     var element = $(Event.findElement(event, 'tr'));
>     alertAlreadyDisplayed = false;
>     if(element){
>         element.down('input[type="hidden"].__delete__').value = '1';
>         Element.select(element, 'div.flex').each(function(elm){
>             elm.remove();
>         });
>         element.addClassName('no-display');
>         element.addClassName('ignore-validate');
>         element.hide();
>     }
> },
> ```

This will solve the BUG